# React Native app is recognized as a game on Samsung Note8

Tags: react-native, samsung-mobile

I wrote react native application. The application is simple, more informational, it is used by Redux, Saga, several linked npm packages. The app runs in normal mode, not full-screen. The structure of the application was built on the basis of Ignite.

The problem is that on the phone (Samsung Note8) the application is recognized as a game. E.g. while app is running there is a message "The game is running" on the lock screen. Also there are additional buttons for the gamepad or something like that. In additional, app has a paddings on the top and on the bottom when it's working on real device (Samsung Note8). This effect real exists when some games running. When app is running on another device (e.g. ZTE Blade 610) it's running as usual and without any side effects.

The main version is the cause of all is Game Tools that's existed on Samsung Note8 but others apps have no similar effects and running as expected.

Is there a possibility to make a react native app as a real app but not a game? Why Game Tools recognizes my app as a game? Or what is the reason and how can it be affected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are few possibilities.

1. you (or one of your dependencies) have included the google play service API which inside of play service API has a module named games that samsung will automatically treat it as game.

You could find which of your dependency is loading google play service API and create a exclude like:

```
compile (project ('your.dependency')){
   exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module:'play-services-game'
}
```

2. Your application id (can see on build.gradle) is registered on samsung game database. You could check by going into playstore and search for your application id

Answer (score 0):

this is something that can happen on samsung phones due to the package name of your app.

we cant change this after the initial release, you must contact samsung developer support and they can fix it on the fly.

i wrote a gist on github about it:

https://gist.github.com/Adnan-Bacic/718eb3b4e70380696c91dc21c4804112